# Making a div stretch the whole screen minus its margin

Tags: html, css

How do I create a Layout-Container that takes up all of the screen estate minus it's margin? I tried using the `calc` function in conjunction with `vh` (calc(100vh-2em)) to no avail. Is there an elegant way to do this without javascript?

Same goes for adjusting the height of the sidebar, so it won't stretch over the container.

Thank you.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
 padding: 0em;
 margin: 0em;
 background-color: white;
 height: 100%;
}

header {padding-bottom:2em;border-bottom:1px dashed white;}


#container{margin:2em; background-color:blue;min-height:100vh; height:100%; }

#sidemenu {
 opacity:0;
 float: left;
 position: fixed;
 width: 15%;
 background-color: green;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: scroll;
 margin-right: 1em;
 font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
 -o-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
 transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;


}

#sidemenu:hover {opacity:1; }

aside {
 line-height: 150%;
}

svg { display:block; margin:2em auto;}

aside ul {
 list-style: none;
 top: 10px;
 left: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 overflow: scroll;
 padding-left: 1em;
}
aside p {
}
aside ul>ul>li {
 font-size: 0.8em;
 color: white;
}
aside a {
 color: black;
}
aside h1 {
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-left: 1em;
 margin-left: 0em;
 font-size: 1em;
}
main {
 float: left;
 width: 43%;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 18%;
 margin-right: 1%;
 display: block;
 background-color:red;
 padding:2em;
}

titel {
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align: left;
 display: block;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
 background-color: red;
 font-size: 5em;
}
.bigger {
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #FFF;
 color: black;
 
 
}
h2 {
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
 color: white;
 font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}


.col h2 {
 color: #FFF;
}
#elcuerpo {
}
.koerper:hover {
 background-color: green;
 transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
}
#tips li {
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}
s
.rules:hover {
 transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
 background-color: white;
}
#sectionside {
 
 overflow: scroll;
 padding-left: 1em;
 right: 5em;
 position: absolute;
 float: right;
 width: 15%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
 color: white;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 height: 100%;}
 
#sectionside ul {
 list-style: none;
 
}
#sectionside h2 {color:white; font-size:0.5em;}

#sectionside li {padding-bottom:2em; font-size:1.5em; font-family:Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif; display:block; margin:0 auto; }
.titel:hover {
 background-color: orange;
}
.intro {
 margin-top:0em;
 padding-top:0em;
 font-size:4em;
 color: white;
 text-align: left;
 text-shadow: 2px 0 #000000;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>A Website</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<aside id="sidemenu">
  <svg height="100" width="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="white"  class="logo"/>
  </svg>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Sone">Section One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Stwo">Sectino Two</a></li>
    <li><a>Section Three</a></li>
    <li><a>Section IV</a></li>
    <li><a>Section V</a></li>
    <li><a>Section V</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li>Subsection</li>
      <li>Subsection</li>
      <li>Subsection</li>
      <li>Subsection</li>
      <li>Subsection</li>
      <li>Subsection</li>
      <li>Subsection</li>
      <li>Subsection</li>
      <li>Subsection</li>
      <li>Subsection</li>
      <li>Subsection</li>
      <li>Subsection</li>
    </ul>
    <li> <a>Section VI</a></li>
    <li>Section VI</li>
  </ul>
</aside>
<main>
  <header>
    <titel>HTML &amp; CSS</titel>
  </header>
  <section id="section one">
    <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </section>
  <div id="sectionone">
    <h2>Display: Inline</h2>
    <p> Display Inline will not break the Layout, it can push other elements away horizontally, but not vertically. It also can not take height or width values. 
  </div>
  <h2>Display: Inline-Block</h2>
  <p>An element set to inline-block is very similar to inline in that it will set inline with the natural flow of text (on the "baseline"). The difference is that you are able to set a width and height which will be respected.</p>
</main>
<section id="sectionside">
  <h2>Rules</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</container>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Something where the content takes up 100% of the `vh`, but has padding on the sides? https://jsfiddle.net/bgmd12kb/ -- Can't you just set `height: 100vh` and use a negative `margin-top`? Please update your question to **clearly** demonstrate what you're trying to achieve -- your sample is an absolute mess.

Comment: I want a div that has a margin, that houses a site/information sort of like a presentation slide - hence it should fill the screen top to bottom, but have an outside margin on all sides, not just left and right. The Sidebars inside that divs should also not stretch outside of that container. I'll try to clean up my posted code. Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calc, like you tried, is the right way to go. However with a couple of slight tweaks. And 4em as your margin is 2em on either side.:

```
width:calc(100vw - 4em);
height:calc(100vh - 4em);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gxkkeyof/) I used 4.1em here so I could have a border to make it easier to see :)

Comment: Thanks! The container works great now, must have made an error. But I still can't get to sidebars (#sectionside and #sidemenu) to not overflow the container, but still be scrollable. Also would there be a better more widely supported way to achieve this layout?

Comment: I don't see any issue with the approach you're using, unless you need to support IE8 and below. IE9+ and all major browsers support calc and vh/vw sizing. For the scollbar, I'm going to cheat and link you to another stackoverflow post where someone outlined a bunch of different working ways to do it :) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll)